# Limit deleting to the uploader

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, item-level-permissions

I am trying to limit it so you can only delete the files you uploaded yourself. Also, make it so you can only delete files not folders.

Comment: Try this: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/03/set-item-level-permission-options-in-document-library.html

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using designer workflow:

1. Upload a file.
2. Trigger a workflow, which grants Delete permission to Created By.
3. User has enough permission to delete the file he uploaded.

How to set item level permission using designer workflow:
http://spcycle.blogspot.sg/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html